# Extracting strings from a Grid expression

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a complicated, hairy expression. I want to extract subexpressions that match a pattern.

```
expr =
  Grid[
    {{"5"}, {Style["1", FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]}}, 
    Frame -> {{All, {}}, {All, {}}}, 
    ItemSize -> {{Automatic, {}}, {Automatic, {}}}]
```

I can sort of do this with

```
Part[expr, Flatten[Position[expr, a_String], 1]]
```

but this seems very convoluted.

This operation seems so fundamental!

Is there a simple way to do this? Something like

```
 someFunction[expr, a_String]
```

> `{"5", "1"}`

Comment: Try to copy as Input Text. p.s. Take a look at `Cases` and its third argument: `Cases[expr, _String, \[Infinity]]`

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the `Cases` function.

Trying

```
Cases[expr, _String]
```

will return an empty list. You need to give `Cases` a level specification.

```
Cases[expr, _String, Infinity]

(* {"5", "1"} *)
```